# MYSQL: Summary Data Query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, summary

So,  I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(mailing_recipient_id) AS Total_Recipient, 
(SELECT COUNT(mailing_recipient_click_id) 
ORDER BY(mailing_recipient_click_type_id)) AS Open_Count, 
(SELECT COUNT(cons_action_contribution_id)) AS Total_Donations, 
(SELECT COUNT(cons_id) ORDER BY cons_action_contribution_id) AS Donations_Per_Recipient 
FROM cons LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient
ON cons.cons_id =mailing_recipient.cons_id
JOIN mailing
ON mailing_recipient.mailing_id = mailing.mailing_id
JOIN mailing_recipient_click
ON mailing_recipient_click.mailing_recipient_id = mailing_recipient.mailing_recipient_id
JOIN cons_action_contribution 
ON cons_action_contribution.con_id = cons.cons_id
GROUP BY(mailing_id);
```

What I am hoping to achieve is a summary including recipient count, open count, opens per recipient, click count, clicks per recipient, number of donation, and donations per recipient.

That is not what I am a getting, and I am unsure why.

mailing_recipient_click_id shows if someone open/clicked the email.

mailing_recipient_click_type_id (1=click, 2=open)

I'm failing to get tables now, but What I am hoping to achieve is the following:

```
Mailing  Recipient    Open    Open_per    Clicks    Click_per    Donation    Donation_per  
1        10000       5000    5           4000      3            500         2  
2        5000        2500    1           4000      1            50          1
```

Comment: please post the sample tables, current output and expected output. I cannot imagine what is in your mind

Comment: You specify three output fields in your query, and expect to get 8 fields? That's more than strange.